# Android Studio congela em Gradle: Resolve dependencies ':app:_debugCompile'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Quando abro o Android Studio o Gradle executa vários processos. Ao chegar em `Resolve dependencies ':app:_debugCompile'` ele trava e mesmo mandando abortar não responde.

Este é o meu `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

O proxy está configurado e a conexão com a internet funciona.

Comment: Olá! Qual a versão do seu Android Studio? Tentou reiniciar a máquina/android studio?

Comment: Android Studio 1.3.1, já reiniciei a máquina. Uso Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Tente dar um Clean Project e depois Rebuild Project.

Comment: Quando faço o Clean Project ele enrosca em Gradle Build Running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu resolvi adicionando as seguintes linhas no arquivo `gradle.properties`, dentro do diretório do projeto:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.empresa.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=10.2.1.0/24, 127.0.0.1

systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.empresa.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=10.2.1.0/24, 127.0.0.1
```

Na verdade, no meu arquivo eu não tinha apenas as configurações referentes ao HTTPS.